How should we handle questions that require mostly speculative answers?
Primary question in question being What is the maximal value of 1 BTC?
I feel like this and other questions require answers that can only be suggested based on speculation, be it researched opinion or merely a historical reoccurrence. 
Should questions like this be permitted, so as to engage in potentially productive discussion, or should they be closed because a definitive answer cannot be reached, rather only agreed upon as a consensus? I understand that SE works on consensus, using votes to express the best answer or best way to solve a problem, but when all answers are speculative, well, it becomes a popularity contest of plausibility.

No matter how productive the discussion might be, StackExchange wasn't built to handle discussions, it was build to handle Q&A. Anything soliciting discussion or purely speculative should be closed as non-constructive.
If people want to engage in speculative or other non-constructive discussion on the SE site they should really do it in chat.
